# show that $\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{15}$ is non-square integer

Tags: number-theory

Let $a,b,c$ be non-zero integers. Show that

$\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{15}$ is a not a perfect square for all $a,b,c$

My approach is the following:

Assume there exists an integer $d$ such that
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=15d^2$$
It follows that
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=15d^2\equiv -d^2\pmod 8\Longrightarrow a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2\equiv 0\pmod 8$$
Well and now I'm stuck and don't know how to proceed

Comment: No,you eaxmple is not such it

Comment: Those values give $(a^2+b^2+c^2)/15=495$, which is not a perfect square? @Brent

Comment: yeah sorry, I misread the question and thought I deleted my comment haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there.  Now note that all squares are $0,1$ or $4 \pmod 8$, so $a,b,c,d$ must be even because if one is odd you can't sum to zero.  Given a solution with $a,b,c,d$ even, you can divide them all by $2$ and have a new solution.  Infinite descent.  Of course, you need to exclude $a=b=c=d=0$

Comment: Or $4$, but it works the same.

Comment: Actually, all squares are 0 or 1 (mod 4).  Try $6^2 (mod 8) = 4$.

Comment: @Nathanson: working $\pmod 4$ you could have all the variables odd, so the descent fails. I was keying off the OP's use of $\pmod 8$

Comment: I'm not having a good night tonight,so maybe I should quit while I'm ahead.

Comment: @Michael:  I missed the point of your post. It is still true that four squares summing to zero $\pmod 8$ must have all the numbers even, so you can divide them all by $2$.  Updated

Comment: @RossMillikan I was talking about the remainder $4$ that was missing before.

Comment: @Nathanson:  Yes, I figured that out.  I missed your point initially, but finally got there. You are right that it works h same.