# How to prove that the equation $3(a^2+b^2)=7(c^2+d^2)$ has no solution

Tags: number-theory

> Question 1: Let $a,b,c,d$ be positive integers, show that
>
> $$3(a^2+b^2)=7(c^2+d^2)$$ has no solution.

question 1 is from [Mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185535/representing-every-positive-rational-number-in-the-form-of-anbn-cndn), Curious How prove it?

> My question 2: Find the least positive integer $k$ such that
> $$a^2+b^2=k(c^2+d^2)$$ has no solution.

Comment: Please put question 2 in a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT for Question 1 :

We have $$c^2+d^2\equiv 0\pmod 3\Rightarrow c\equiv d\equiv 0\pmod 3$$ and $$a^2+b^2\equiv 0\pmod 7\Rightarrow a\equiv b\equiv 0\pmod 7.$$

So, since we have $a=7p,b=7q,c=3r,d=3s,$ we have
$$3(a^2+b^2)=7(c^2+d^2)\Rightarrow 7(p^2+q^2)=3(r^2+s^2).$$

Comment: Thanks,But you think the question 2 find it?

Comment: The analysis mod $7$ is unneeded, since we have $\,9\mid$ RHS so $\,3\mid a^2+b^2\,\Rightarrow\, 3\mid a,b\,$ hence descent.

Comment: @BillDubuque: You are right. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{a^2+b^2}{c^2+d^2}=\frac{(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)}{(c^2+d^2)^2}$$

Use [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity) for the numerator to get $$\frac{a^2+b^2}{c^2+d^2}=\left(\frac{ac\pm bd}{c^2+d^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{ad\mp bc}{c^2+d^2}\right)^2$$

But $3,7\equiv-1\pmod4$  can not be expressed as the sum of two squares

Comment: Hello,so you think which is minumin of the $k$?

Comment: @abandon, If $k>1,k=2$ as $2(a^2+b^2)=(a+b)^2+(a-b)^2$

Comment: Hello,But $\dfrac{7}{3}\equiv \dfrac{3}{3}=1\pmod 4$?

Comment: @abandon, We need each of $7,3$ to be of the form sum of two squares

Comment: why can't expressed sum of  two squares?

Comment: @abandon, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares

Comment: Thank you,I have use this methods to solve it,http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199216/show-that-fraca2b2c215-is-non-square-integer

Comment: because $$a^2+b^2+c^2\equiv 0\pmod 8$$

Answer (score 1):

The famous two-square theorem by Fermat implies that $3n$ is not the sum of two squares, if $n$ is. This is answers Question $2$.

The first question is a nice example of infinite descent. One can show that all four numbers are dibisible by $3$, if the equation holds. Hence we get a smaller solution by dividing the equation by $9$.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: c and d are both $0\mod3$, so RHS is divisible by 9, which means a and b are both $0 \mod 3$, so LHS divisible by 27, etc...

Q2: k=3 by similar argument to Q1.